# phpBB3 can't restore between english version and chinese version

Tags: phpbb3

I have installed two phpBB ,one is on my free web disk ,
it's a chinese version;the other is on my local pc,it's a english version .
Today i backuped all phpBB material from my free web disk (english version),
and saved it in the restore dir in my local phpBB ,
when i restored it in my local phpBB ,enter my local phpBB  `127.0.0.1\phpBB`,got the output.

```
Language file ./language/zh_cmn_hans/common.php couldn't be opened.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you back up the Chinese sites database then restore it to your local site? If so, the local site is looking for the Chinese language files.
To fix this, download the Chinese files and save them to the /language/ directory on your local machine.